Trying to flip animation, getting a bad result, is there a fix?
I googled a way to flip a animation and tried the ctrl+shift+v keyframe method but the result is poor, am I doing something wrong? Video included
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dYqbZN0BuhY

there may be 2 problems: wrong names for the bones (they all need to have the correct suffixes, like arm_R and arm_L) or wrong rotation, hard to tell without the file, maybe share it here: https://blend-exchange.com/
